# Disallow MouseEvent with ESLint (Typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mouseevent, eslint

I am trying to enforce a rule to disallow things like this:

```
const submit = (event: React.MouseEvent) => {};
```

and instead do this:

```
const submit: React.MouseEventHandler = (event) => {};
```

I tried with something like this:

```
"no-restricted-imports": ["error", {
  "paths": [{
    "name": "react",
    "importNames": ["MouseEvent"],
    "message": "Please use MouseEventHandler."
  }]
}]
```

But it only works if I do this:

```
import { MouseEvent } from 'react';
```

If people use it like this: `React.MousEvent` ESLint doesn't error. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a rule to disallow usage of the name `React.MouseEvent` isntead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use ESLint rule called [typescript-eslint/ban-types](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/ban-types.md)

You can add this in your `.eslintrc.js` file

```
"@typescript-eslint/ban-types": ["error",
    {
        "types": {
            "React.MouseEvent": { "message": "Please avoid using React.MouseEvent" }
        },
        "extendDefaults": true
    }
],
```